# Why does we have a type mismatch?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have written a program to see, how **string literals** been deduced in template functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> void passByValue(T by_value)
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<char const*, decltype(by_value)> << std::endl; // okay
}

template<typename T> void passByReferance(T &by_ref)
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<char const*, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(by_ref)>> << std::endl;
}

template<typename T> void passByConstRef(const T &const_ref)
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<char const*, std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(const_ref)>>> << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    passByValue("string");    // true: good
    passByReferance("string");// false ??
    passByConstRef("string"); // false ??
    return 0;
}
```

It turns out that, only for the **passByValue** the string literals deduced to `const char*` type.

In other two cases(**passByReferance** and **passByConstRef**), if we apply to the deduced arguments, `std::remove_reference_t` and `std::remove_const_t`, what I we suppose to get is `const char*`, is that correct?

I get a type match when I do complete decay using `std::decay_t`, why is that?

Comment: The answer covers all the details. If you need better visibility of the types, you can use the helpers here: https://godbolt.org/z/AqTA0e

Comment: @balki Thats nice: your code demonstrates the view of the machine. Could you post it in the answer section? At least I can give you thumbs up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing `const char[7]` not `const char *`. Arrays and pointers are not the same things. They are often confused because arrays easily decay to pointers to their first element. When taken by reference, arrays don't need to decay to pointers. Only in the first case does your array need to decay to a pointer.

The following tests produces `true` for each case :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> void passByValue(T by_value)
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<char const*, decltype(by_value)> << std::endl; 
}

template<typename T> void passByReferance(T &by_ref)
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<char const[7], std::remove_reference_t<decltype(by_ref)>> << std::endl;
}

template<typename T> void passByConstRef(const T &const_ref)
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<char [7], std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(const_ref)>>> << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    passByValue("string");    
    passByReferance("string");
    passByConstRef("string"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Edit : As for [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), it explicitly causes array types to decay to pointers :

> If `T` names the type "array of `U`" or "reference to array of `U`", the member typedef type is `U*`.

Comment: then what happens in the case of [applying `std::decay_t`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dad21b056f50412)

Comment: @JoeyMallone Don't use plain arrays and you never have to worry about this. `std::array` and `std::string`/`std::string_view` should suffice.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, yes, thank you. I learn something new, everyday here.

Comment: @Const Moved my comment to the answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, that's true, I was keep thinking that `std::decay` makes it `const char*` but the ones I used not. This clarifies me the doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some helpers to get better view of the types. CE: https://godbolt.org/z/6EFmIR

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct Tis { Tis(); };

template<bool b>
struct Truth{ Truth(); };

template<typename T> void passByValue(T by_value)
{
    Tis<T>{}; //call    Tis<char const*>::Tis()
    Truth<
        std::is_same_v<char const*, decltype(by_value)>
    >{}; // call    Truth<true>::Truth()
}

template<typename T> void passByReferance(T &by_ref)
{
    Tis<T>{}; // call    Tis<char const [7]>::Tis()
    Tis<decltype(by_ref)>{}; // call    Tis<char const (&) [7]>::Tis()
    Truth<
        std::is_same_v<char const*, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(by_ref)>> 
    >{}; // call    Truth<false>::Truth()
    Tis<
        std::remove_reference_t<decltype(by_ref)>
    >{}; // call    Tis<char const [7]>::Tis()
}

template<typename T> void passByConstRef(const T &const_ref)
{
    Tis<T>{}; // call    Tis<char [7]>::Tis()
    Truth<
        std::is_same_v<char const*, std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(const_ref)>>> 
    >{}; // call    Truth<false>::Truth()
    Tis<
        std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(const_ref)>>
    >{}; // call    Tis<char [7]>::Tis()
}

void foo1(){
    passByValue("string");
}
void foo2() {
    passByReferance("string");
}
void foo3() {
    passByConstRef("string");
}
```